# Migrating Drupal site - URL aliases = 404 Not Found

Tags: amazon-web-services, drupal, migration, drupal-path-aliases

I am migrating a Drupal site from Host X to Amazon Web Services...this isn't my first site migration, nor am I new to AWS (it's not my security settings, it's not apache).  I had this problem a while back with another site, but due to the time-sensitive nature of my problem, I simply took the source, created a local test site on my PC, changed the URL alias setting, and re-deployed the code.  Bam, no problem, everything works.

I did a search and found some suggestions on how to remedy this issue, but can't find what I would consider an approach that yields a thorough understanding of what I'm working with.  So, I don't want to install a module, or change the original site and remove the URL aliases permanently.

I need to be able to solve this problem in less-than-ideal situations.

I need to know how to remove URL aliases manually (e.g. in either phpmyadmin or in the MySQL server itself), and how to configure said aliases so that I can retain their use, but still have my +20 pages show up.  Right now all that shows is index.php, and if I use ?q=user, I can log in, but it throw a 404 once I do.  If I return to index.php it shows the admin console above the page, but, again, every other page throws a 404.

Can someone point me in the right direction (that doesn't involve more modules or removing URL aliases all together)?

Comment: It sounds like you are missing an .htaccess file with rewrite rules?

Answer (score 0):

Disregard.  I found the answer.

In .htaccess enable RewriteBase /example/of/your/site

And in your Apache2 default file under /etc/apache2/sites-available, change 
AllowOverride None to AllowOverride All (under /var/www)